# Vaadin Dialog resize programmatically

Tags: vaadin

Vaadin 14.2.0.alpha7 added new functionality to Dialog component (https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.2.0.alpha7/com/vaadin/flow/component/dialog/Dialog.html), especially the resizing availability. Unfortunately I was unable to find a way to have dialog being created with width I need neither to set the width programmatically after the dialog is opened.

Here are few lines of code I use for described purposes (unsuccessfully):

```
    dialog.isResizable = true

    dialog.width = "900px"


    dialog.addOpenedChangeListener { event ->

        println("!!!opened-changed event fired")

        dialog.width = "900px"

        println("!!!dialog width = ${dialog.width}")
    }

    dialog.addResizeListener { event ->

        println("!!! on resize event width = ${dialog.width}")
    }
```

When I open the dialog it appears with its limited width (around 500px), the OpenedChanged event being fired and prints that dialog has 900px width (while its not!), when I resize it manually the Resize event being fired and prints that dialog has around 600px width (after I increased it a bit manually using mouse).

I know that early versions of Dialog had limited width (around 500px) in templates and there is workaround with importing styles to adjust dialog width. I was hoping with new version to increase dialog width without touching templates and client-side.

Is there any way to set dialog width and adjust on being opened programmatically without touching client-side templates?

P.S. The 14.2.0 version announced to be published on April so I believe the question is suitable even for now its prerelease version.

Comment: Hello, I tried the same approach in a new project taken from vaadin.com/start/ and changing the Vaadin version to `14.2.0.alpha7` as you used. When I opened the dialog, I could see the overlay with `900px` width as expected. Also, setting the width at the `openedChangedListener` worked. Could you try running it in a fresh project just to confirm that issue?

Comment: Hello, @DiegoCardoso and thanks for the feedback. 

I've created a new project by deleting everything not concerned to the subject (a new project with new folder, pom.xml etc.) and uploaded it to git - https://github.com/itslarin/vaadin_14.2.0.alpha7. 

And i have exactly the same situation - the dialog have been created with default size, while prinitng its width is 900px, when i resize it manually it prints it has 594px (after i enlarged its width a bit).

To avoid possible misunderstanging - i use monitor with 1920*1200 resolution. Maybe u got 900px cos of different screen resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens due to the `max-width` setting of ~`560px` to comply with the **materials** design. There is a ticket about it here: [Dialog Size - Material Theme](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-dialog/issues/127). (In the default Lumo theme this works out of the box. You can verify it by commenting out `@Theme(value = Material::class, variant = Material.LIGHT)` in `MainLayout.kt`)

Unfortunately, as style targets the `overlay` part, the only one way to overcome this is using style files. On the other hand, it should be pretty straightforward in the current version :)

I created a pull request to your repo with the changes needed. Feel free to use it, if you want [Make width acccept values more than 500px](https://github.com/itslarin/vaadin_14.2.0.alpha7/pull/1) :)

Comment: thanks for the help, it works! My fault i havent dig deep into frontend assuming there should be strictly server-side solution as long as vendor made the dialog resizable.

As long as its a theme limitation and now i believe there is no programmatical way to overcome my issue without touching templates i will mark your answer as the solution and will skip my github example untouched with your pr for public in case anybody else will face the same situation.